# Redux-React Best practice (performances issues)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

do you know a proper way to use shouldComponentUpdate with redux

lets take my code as example:

```
import React from 'react';


@connect((store) => {
    return {
        data: store.Reducer..data,
        labels: store.Reducer.labels,
    };
})
export default class Bar_Comp extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    componentWillMount() {

        this.props.dispatch(Action.GetListdata());

        var data = {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: []
                }
            ]
        };
        this.setState({ data: data, lastIndex: 1 });

    }
    getElementAtEvent(elemn) {
        if (elemn[0]) {
                .
                .
                .
                this.props.dispatch(Action.action2(datasets[elemn[0]._index - 1], labels[elemn[0]._index - 1]))


        }
    }
        shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

        if (_.isEmpty(nextProps.labels))
            return false;
        else if (_.isEqual(nextProps.labels, this.props.labels))
            return false;
        return true;

} 
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

        if (!_.isEmpty(nextProps.data) && _.isEqual(nextProps.data, this.props.data)) {
            ....

            datasets = functions based on nextProps ...
            labels = functions based on nextProps ...
            this.setState({ data: data, RawListATA: nextProps.data, labels: nextProps.labels });
            this.props.dispatch(reportAction.method(datasets[0], labels[0]))
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <Bar data={this.state.data} title='Count' getElementAtEvent={this.getElementAtEvent.bind(this)} />
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

as you can see in my case, when I receive a new props data, I redraw my bar chart (by setting new states), then dispatch a new actions

So, for me, I have to do a double check:
once in componentWillReceiveProps to set new states, and shouldComponentUpdate to stop unnecessary updates.
But I think that this solution is not a good, so do you have any suggestions to improve this code performances

Comment: I have made the following assumption(from some stuff I read here and there): You have parent component A and child component B. Component A contain component B. Both connect to two separate items in the store(i.e. No props are passed from A to B). If items for component A change in the store, A will re-render. Under normal circumstances B will be re-rendered as well but because its hooked up to the redux store it wont. I am not sure were I have seen it but using redux removes the responsibility on you to use shouldComponentUpdate

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but as you said, with redux, if a component updated, all other components will re-render because they are connected to the same store because the props (store) is changed, and that what I am trying to avoid. to give you the real pb, lets take this case: if I remove the check in componentWillReceiveProps method, I will have an infinite loop, because, when component A change B should be changed (store is updated), then A will change (because the store is updated), then B will re-render, then A then B.(so it will create a loop) and after 10 seconds my application crashed

Comment: That won't happen if you avoid passing the whole store.

Comment: check the answer here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285200/react-redux-performance-optimization-with-componentshouldupdate

Comment: Thanks, it seems interesting, I will check it